# laravel blade variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I tried to access variable inside blade syntax:

```
            success: function(resp) {
                console.log(resp)
                var MsgClass = 'alert-danger';
                $("#overlay").hide();
                if(resp.success) {
                    MsgClass = 'alert-success';
                    window.location.href = "{{ asset('public/exports/'+resp.filename) }}"
                }                    
            },
```

But I get

```
Use of undefined constant resp - assumed 'resp'
```

How can I get this variable inside the syntax?

Comment: `{{ asset('public/exports/') }} + resp.filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use like this

```
window.location.href = '"{{url('')}}/public/exports/"'+resp.filename
```

Comment: That `+'}}"'` at the end shouldn't be required.